# Resumable archive

Tags: tar, archive

I've a need to archive some big directory structures on an NFS server. They're not likely to be needed particularly soon, if ever - they're just being retained for policy reasons.

To this end, I'm making tarballs, and probably eventually writing them out to tape.

There's just one problem - I'm having a bit of difficult with the really large volumes (10TB+) - the runtime is sufficiently long that it gets left overnight, and in a few cases it seems to have 'stalled' - it's not too easy to tell for a backgrounded `tar xvfz`.

And then things like running out of space, network interruption etc. means that for things that don't complete in a single session, I'm not entirely sure that the archive is a) complete and b) entirely valid.

So hoping for some advice - ideally what I'd like is something resumable, like rsync, which I can multi-pass the copy, without starting over.

Is there a way to "rsync to a tar.gz"? 
A not-too-expensive way of verifying file writes?  I'm currently looking at 'extract, shasum and compare' but that's also a rather expensive/intensive process.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps splitting your backups would be a step towards addressing your problem?

`tar cvzf - /your/dir/ | split --bytes=1000MB - backup.tar.gz`

Or you can look into `dar`, perhaps. It has splitting built-in:
http://dar.linux.free.fr/doc/Features.html

I also found some info on how to resume an interrupted `dar` backup job that might help:

http://sourceforge.net/p/dar/mailman/message/30863378/

Comment: Could you include the relevant info about resuming in your question please? That link might break, making your answer far less useful.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that the operation was successful, just add `&& echo` something to each `tar` operation:

```
tar cvzf target.tar "$source" && echo "$source tarred successfully" >> progress.log
```

It won't help you resume, but at least, that way you'll know whether your `tar` worked.

Another thing that might help would be to first gzip and *then* tar:

```
find "$source" -type f -exec gzip {} + && tar cvf "$source".tgz "$source" && 
    echo "$source tarred successfully" >> progress.log
```

That way, you can easily check whether a file was compressed or not. The `tar` operation is relatively cheap, it's the compression that slows it down. By decoupling the two, you'll be able to get more fine grained control.